# "Ready, Set, Go!" in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom, modern-life

How would you translate the common sport phrase into Latin. Here is my thought thus far:

**Ready.**

It usually used to mean "on your marks". But I would like to take it as "prepare!", so **para** or even in passive voice **parare** (be you ready) if that makes sense.

**Set.**

Struggled on this one. If we attribute the meaning of *arrange*/*direct*/*aim*, **derige** or even **intende** might be possibilities. or rather **para** is actually better here.

**Go!**

Yet another difficulty. It seems the regular verbs of walking (*vado*, *eo*, *ambulo*, etc) do not fit here. I resorted to the Vulgate Gen. 12:1 ("“Go from your country, your people and your father’s household"), since I thought that that "Go" or "לך" in the original Hebrew is closer, since IMO it also captures, in that context, the idea of "start"; new action(leave where are you now) etc. It uses **egredere**. (which is quite long. Preferably, this should not be longer than 2 syllables)

Ended up with **"parare, derige, egredere"** (or other combination from the above), but had some problematic selections, so your versions/reviews are welcome. Personally, I like the imperative mood for all 3, but certainly it might be different. Bonus points if your selection of "Go!" can be written on a "go" button. (i.e button that starts something, or init an action); other bonus-points if the words are "in harmony" with each other, i.e an holistic selection that takes into account all words and the spirit and the flow of the phrase, rather than simply word to word selection as done above.

Answer (score 6):

So, I'd recommend something like this:

*Cursores, parate vos, ite/decurrite!*

Literally: Runners, prepare yourselves... Go/Run!

With *paro* you would want to use a pronoun reflexively, as the verb is transitive (takes a direct object).

An important thing to remember when translating is that a literal translation is often not the best one. You have to bear in mind that there are many words that mean go, that mean begin, that mean run. *decurro* is mentioned in the OLD specifically with races, *eo* is a general word for go regardless of speed. Also, while I personally am working on a project for the Vulgate, and know it pretty well. It is not the best option to use "reverse translation" on to find what you need in Latin. Bible translations take... a few *liberties* when putting the books into English, and some of the Latin, Greek or Hebrew *flavor* is lost.

And for your future reference: *emitto -ere* is used to describe the release of runners to start a race. *emittuntur* would be a quasi-"and they're off"

Answer (score 2):

The English phrase can be used for things other than runners. Perhaps, "Comites, Parate vos, Facite/Agite." "Comerades, Prepare yourselves, Do/Act!"

My answer is mostly modeled on Colin's format, I just wanted to throw out another option for a different interpretation.